# How to insert text into multiple text files using a .bat file?

Tags: batch-file

I having drouble to create a batch file that can insert text into multiple text files at once.

What I can do just now is that one file that I drop on the batch file is getting inserted with the text "I AM PROGRAMMING".
But I would like to drag multiple text files and that all of it/each every text file gets inserted with that text.

```
@echo off
echo I AM PROGRAMMING> "%~1"
```

Or if there is somehow possible to do so every text file in a specific place/folder gets inserted with a specific text (for example "I AM PROGRAMMING")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution processes each matching file in the folder, but you said `I would like to drag multiple text files`.

It's easy to process "multiple dragged files": `%*` is "all parameters". Just use a plain `for` loop to process each of them:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (%*) do echo I AM PROGRAMMING> "%%~a"
```

(note that this overwrites the files with the one new line; if you want to append, use `>>` instead of `>`)

In case you want to process "all .txt files in the folder of the one file I dragged":

```
for %%a in ("%~dp1\*.txt") do ...
```

Or "all files in the same folder of the one file I dragged and the same extension as the dragged file":

```
for %%a in ("%~dp1*%~x1") do  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution!

```
@echo off
cd "yourfilepath"
for %%a in (*.txt) do (echo I AM PROGRAMMING> %%a)
```

I merged these two helpful information.

[How can I use a batch file to write to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878136/how-can-i-use-a-batch-file-to-write-to-a-text-file)
And
[Append multiple files using a .bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648253/append-multiple-files-using-a-bat)